# Devexpress combobox cannot be emptied with ValueType=Int32

Tags: devexpress, aspxcombobox

I [already opened a bug](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B196121.aspx), but since I need this ready yesterday (typical, isn't it?), I'll try asking here as well.

I have an ASPxComboBox with some items and `ValueType="System.Int32"` When I call on client side `SetSelectedIndex(-1)`, the combobox is cleared (as expected), but upon postback the previously selected item is active again.

Any ideas on how to make it stay empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the latest Suite version (10.2.4) and upgrade your application.  I have checked how your code works using 10.2.4 and do not see this problem.

Comment: Ahh... I'll try, although, to be honest, the last upgrade was a pretty big hassle already. It would be great if you could try this on 10.2.3 and maybe give me some hints. But thank you!